# The meaning of the name of a movie

Tags: meaning

I have watched a cool movie with the title 'The Houses October Built', but I cannot understand the name. What does houses October built mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like an odd and artsy title that personifies the month of October, referring to houses which were built by the month, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

October is the month of Halloween, ghosts, scary things and **haunted houses**.

[The Houses October Built - IMDB Description](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1958043/):

> Five friends are stalked by a group of mysterious and disturbed individuals while on a road trip looking for the ultimate haunted house attraction.

People create haunted houses in October because of Halloween, and the rest of the year, those "houses" are turned back into normal spaces.

So you could say that October is responsible for why people build [haunted] houses.